# Glassfish 3.1.2 and EJB Timer - How to get my timer back

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3

The following happened. I overtook a Java project on a Glassfish server. Now the timed reporter does not work any more due to a twice exception incident. The log says:

```
[#|2014-02-19T08:00:36.179+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=112;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5119:Expunging timer ['2@@1368688442192@@server@@domain1' 'TimedObject = TimerBean' 'Application = MY_APP' 'BEING_DELIVERED' 'PERIODIC' 'Container ID = 89698358364733447' 'Thu May 16 09:00:00 CEST 2013' '86400000' ] after [2] failed deliveries|#]
```

But how can I get this timer back? Do I assume it right, that it must be set somehow in the shown screen "EJB timer service".

http://i.xomf.com/mfqcz.jpg

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs if your timed method(s) throw an exception and can't be completed successfully. The container tries to execute them two times, if it fails both times the Timer will be removed.

To "get your timer back" **you have to fix the problem which causes the exception** and then redeploy your application.

And no, you can't see your Timer on the screen "EJB Timer Service" because this is not a listing or overview but a configuration page.

**See also:**

- [Avoid expunging timer on glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530717/avoid-expunging-timer-on-glassfish)